# Optimal operating system for self-hosted Windows agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We are currently using multiple self-hosted build agents with Windows 10 as the operating system. In various pipelines in Azure Devops (whether Online or OnPremis), we have not had any bad experiences or questioned the OS we chose over the many years.

Now IT approached me and asked if there was anything wrong with using Windows Server 2019/2022 as the OS for a self-hosted build agent. I guess in the long run it would be a price advantage.

But are there any other advantages or disadvantages between Windows Server 2019/2022 and Windows 10/11?

Answer (score 0):

There are no other advantages or disadvantages between Windows Server 2019/2022 and Windows 10/11. Only cost... and maybe system requirements of your build/external components.